# Manage the relationship between three tables

Tags: ajax, database, cakephp-3.0

I am working on a project to list user's skills at sports.
An user can practice up to 5 sports and have a skill rating (0 to 5) for each.

I linked these 3 tables to a 4th other one named "user_sports_and_skills".

So i have 4 table :
users,
sports,
skills,
user_sports_and_skills

The idea is to have a primary key for each new relationship in the "user_sports_and_skills" table, and a foreign key for each other 3 tables.

So, first question : is it a good approach?

Second question:
What i want to do is to set correctly my models and controllers in cakephp 3 to create an entry in a clean way.

I've read the documentation, particulary this : https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html

So i tried something like this which lead me to constraint errors:

```
class UsersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('user_sports_and_skills', [
            'through' => 'sports', 'skills',
        ]);
    }
}
```

So maybe should i create an entity for the "user_sports_and_skills" and write my models differently?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `sports` table that lists all the sports, and a `Users` table for the people - then a single additional `user_sports_and_skills` table would be a good way to list each user's skill at each sport. You may not need a separate table for Skills if it's really just a ranking 0-5, but it could be useful if it was storing more than just a rating (like a label "novice" was 0, "expert" was 5, etc.)

If you have those three tables, then the `users_sports_and_skills` table table would just need the user's ID, the sport's ID, and the skill rating ID, for example:

```
+-----------+------------+------------+
|  user_id  |  sport_id  |  skill_id  |
+-----------+------------+------------+
|        1  |         1  |         4  |
|        1  |         2  |         3  |
|        2  |         1  |         5  |
|        2  |         1  |         2  |
+-----------+------------+------------+
```

Then, since each User will have multiple `user_sports_and_skills` you should be using `hasMany`:

```
class UsersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->hasMany(
            'UserSportsAndSkills',
            [
                'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Optionally Sports table could optionally have the same relationship if you ever wanted to extend it from that direction:

```
class SportsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->hasMany(
            'UserSportsAndSkills',
            [
                'foreignKey' => 'sport_id'
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

And the user_sports_and_skills table would list that each row belongs to a User and a skill:

```
class UsersSportsAndSkillsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsTo(
            'Users',
            [
                'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
            ]
        );
        $this->belongsTo(
            'Sports',
            [
                'foreignKey' => 'sport_id'
            ]
        );
        $this->belongsTo(
            'Skills',
            [
                'foreignKey' => 'skill_id'
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Note that if you follow the above naming conventions (user_id for a reference to the users table), the Bake utility might be able to actually auto-detect these relationships for you.

Could be as simple as 'baking' each of the models, ex:

`cake bake model users_sports_and_skills`

> **More Information:**
>
> - [Bake Usage](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/usage.html)
> - [BelongsTo Docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongsto-associations)
> - [HasMany Docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#hasmany-associations)